# Plot a contour map of v component of geostrophic velocity

Tags: python, velocity, contour

I need your help to figure out the answer for this question. I've spent my 3 days but I haven't still figured out how to do this.
Here my question: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiOuT.png

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58890663/edit) your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including sample input, output, potential traceback and _code for what you have tried_ so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This site isn't a code writing service.